# How to generate random numbers correlated to a given dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, normal-distribution, correlated

I have a matrix x with 10,000 rows and 20 columns. I want to generate another new matrix of random numbers , y, where y is correlated to x with correlation coefficient q.

Note that the matrix x is not normally distributed - it has the power law distribution.

I want to perform this in matlab

Comment: show your code which you tried to solve this issue.

Comment: I found only one sample online which suggests that if I have a normally distributed random numbers , x1, then I can generate a dataset y correlated to x as follows; y = qX + (1-q) X1  -> where q is the correlation coefficient, X is numbers that Y needs to be correlated. But this method only works when the random numbers are normally distributed.

Comment: Y_1 = \rho X_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} X_2

Comment: How is this a programming question? Go read something about **copulas**, make a good faith effort to solve it yourself, and then come back and show us what you've done if you can't get that to work.